# Get getLastModifiedTime(path) in TimeUnit.Days

Tags: java, nio2

I am trying to get the number of days, after the last modification of a given file.

Following code gives me **`18135`** when checked for a file which is just been modified.

### Code

```
public class IOExamples {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Path path = Paths.get("zoo.log"); // zoo.log was just been modified
        System.out.println(Files.getLastModifiedTime(path).to(TimeUnit.DAYS));
    }
}
```

The output is just a number -

### Output

**`18135`**

Please help me get the number of days.

Comment: You get the number of days since the epoch this way. What you need is to subtract the last modified time from the current time and then express the *difference* in days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the difference between now, you could use:

```
Duration.between(Files.getLastModifiedTime(path).toInstant(), Instant.now())
        .toDays()
        ;
```

Note that this may fail if `Instant.now()` returns a value less than `Files.getLastModifiedTime(path).toInstant()` which is possible.

See relevant [Duration::between javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#between-java.time.temporal.Temporal-java.time.temporal.Temporal-)

As per @RealSkeptic comment, you may also use the DAYS enum constant from [ChronoUnit](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html):

```
long days = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(Files.getLastModifiedTime(path).toInstant(), 
                    Instant.now())
        ;
```

Note that the warning about failing if `Files.getLastModifiedTime(path).toInstant()` is greater than `Instant.now()` does not apply: it will simply return a negative number.

Comment: Or just use `DAYS.between`.